# Why do Vedas and Brahma Sutra start with अ?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, rama, upanishads, brahman

Why do Vedas and Brahma Sutra start with अ? Is their any reason for that?

Comment: because akaraartho vishnuh - Sound A stands for Vishnu.

Answer (score 1):

See, Brahma Sūtra & Vedās are in highly coded form as God himslef loves what is described in esoteric terms (परोक्ष=गुप्त रूप). Because according to Maha-Purusha-s these Scriptures are very illusionary as they contains everything and they themselves don't want that people come out from this illusion. जैसे गंगा में प्रत्येक प्रकार का पानी बहता है जैसे नगर का, घर का, किसी राज्य का, किसी नाले का, ठीक उसी प्रकार शास्त्रों में सब मिलता है। That's why learned people always attain that supreme personality only by surrendering to Acharya. Because an Acharya will tell you what you mean to study, how much you have to study. To put it plainly, he will give you nectar from that endless ocean  after drinking which you will become Ānand Swarōop i.e. eternal blissful.

Before starting further I want to say just one thing;

वेद पुराण भी पढ़ कर यदि हरि नहीं मिले तो पूरे जीवन भी शास्त्रों के अध्ययन का कोई लाभ नहीं है।

See, forget “ **अ** “, Even if the Brahma Sutras and the Vedas were to begin with any letter, they would still refer to the Supreme Purusha, Shri Rām. As said by Vedās themselves;

> अकारादिक्षकारान्तवर्णजातकलेवरम् । विकलेवरकैवल्यं रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥

Whose divine form is accumulation of the words starting from “**A-kār**" **(अ से प्रारंभ)** to “**Cha-kār**” **(क्ष तक)**. (यानी अ से लेकर क्ष तक जितने शब्द हैं वह सारे शब्द रघुराई को ही संबोधित करते हैं) Whose form is devoid of “Maya” (चिदानंदमय देह तुम्हारी। बिगत बिकार जान अधिकारी॥) Who is Moksha Swaroop, I worship that supreme purusha Sri Rām's lotus feet.

**(Rigveda Shākha Akshamalika Upanishad 1.1)**

So the very first Shlokā of Vedās, i.e.;

> **अग्निमीळे** पुरोहितं यज्ञस्य देवमृत्विजम् । होतारं रत्नधातमम् ॥

**(Rigveda 1.1.1)**

Donotes Śrī Rām in esoteric terms (गुप्त रूप) because supreme purusha loves what is in esoteric terms as said by Vedas ITSELF;

> परोक्षप्रिया इव हि देवाः

**(Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 4.2.2)**

Bhagavan Shri Rām likes to be referred and described in esoteric terms.

One very interesting thing is that that word Agni **(अग्नि)** himself denotes Śrī Rām. As said by lord Shiva himself in Skandh Purān, Nirvān Khand, Chapter 32;

> रेफोऽग्निरहमेवोक्तो विष्णुः सोमो म उच्यते । आवयोर्मध्यगो ब्रह्मा
> रविराकार उच्यते ॥

The letter **“R”** or **“ र ”** of the name Ram signifies fire, that fire is me. The 'm' in the name of Rama stands for the soma 'Vishnu', and the **“A”** (रा और म के बीच आ की मात्रा) in the middle of the two means Brahma the same denotes the sun also.

Also cleared by Vedās—

> रकारो वह्निवचनः

The Sanskrit alphabet 'Ra, र’ is the Beej (seed/root) Mantra of the 'fire element'.

(वेद अग्नि शब्द से शुरू होकर परोक्ष रूप में यह दर्शाते हैं कि हमारा उद्भव राम नाम से ही हुआ है)

**(Atharvavedā Ram Rahasya Upanishad Chapter 3/Canto 5, Shloka 3)**

So it is clear from here that the word Agni in the starting of Rig Veda refers to the letter “ R ” of the name Shri Ram denoting Śrī Rām alone in the scriptures. As said in Scriptures “ अ ” ITSELF refers to vasudev.

> न वै स आत्मात्मवतां सुहृत्तम: सक्तस्त्रिलोक्यां भगवान् वासुदेव: । न
> स्त्रीकृतं कश्मलमश्नुवीत न लक्ष्मणं चापि विहातुमर्हति ॥

**(Śrīmad Bhāgwatam 5.19.6)**

Since Lord Śrī Rāmacandra is himself Supreme Personality of Godhead, Vāsudeva, He is not attached to anything in this material world. He is the most beloved Supersoul of all self-realized souls, and He is their very intimate friend. He is full of all opulences (षडगुण पूर्ण ऐश्वर्या). Therefore He could not possibly have suffered because of separation from His wife, nor could He have given up His wife and Lakṣmaṇa, His younger brother. To give up either would have been absolutely impossible.

> रामराममहाबाहोनवेद्मित्वांसनातनम्
> जानाम्यद्यैवकाकुत्स्थतववीर्य्यगुणादिभिः ।। त्वमादिपुरुषः
> साक्षात्परब्रह्मपरोऽव्ययः त्वमनंतोमहाविष्णुर्वासुदेवःपरात्परः ।।

Śrī Parshuram to Śrī Rām; O Rām you are Adipurush, certainly Par-Brahma Parmatma, you are Maha-Vishnü & Paratpār Vāsudev. (Paratpār denotes Swāyam Bhagwān)

**(Padma Purana/Vol. 6 (Uttar Khand)/Chapter 242, Verses 169/170)**

Let us understand “Agni” with another example;

> बंदउँ नाम राम रघुबर को। हेतु कृसानु भानु हिमकर को॥ बिधि हरि हरमय बेद
> प्रान सो। अगुन अनूपम गुन निधान सो॥

मैं रघुनाथ के नाम 'राम' की वंदना करता हूँ, जो कृशानु (अग्नि), भानु (सूर्य) और हिमकर (चंद्रमा) का हेतु अर्थात् 'र' 'आ' और 'म' रूप से बीज है। वह 'राम' नाम ब्रह्मा, विष्णु और शिवरूप है। वह वेदों का प्राण है, हीन गुणों से परे, उपमा रहित और गुणों का भंडार है।

Here;

रा = **Fire (अग्नि)**

आ = **Sun (सूर्य)**

म = **Moon (चंद्रमा)**

**(RāmCharit Manas, Balkānd, Doha 19.1)**

Actually this chaupai was direct translation of Skand Purān Nirvān Khand.

It clearly denotes that from the letter “R” of the RAMA the whole Vedas are manifested.

That's why the first word of Rigveda Agni is referring to Shri Rām only. One thing to be noted here that when I say Rama I am basically referring to the all Vishnu tattva as Shri Rām and his other forms has no difference.

Vedas be like:~ Maa Kasam Bro, to be very honest every single Phylosophy in Vedas will take you to the Śrī Rām alone.

> समस्तवेदान्तसारसिद्धान्तार्थकलेवरम्। विकलेवरकैवल्यं रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥

Every single Phylosophy (Sidhhant) of Veda & Vedānt denotes the form of Śrī Rām. Whose form is devoid of Māya, who is Moksha Swarōop, I worship that lotus feet of Śrī Rām.

**(Krishna Yajurvedā Shākhāyam Sarvsaar Upanishad 1.1)**

So it is crystal clear that why Rigved starts from “Agni” as it has to refer his Mater Śrī Rām. As his lord, Śrī Rāghav loves esoteric terms as again said by the lord himself in Śrīmad Bhāgwatam 11.21.35;

> वेदा ब्रह्मात्मविषयास्‍त्रिकाण्डविषया इमे । परोक्षवादा ऋषय: परोक्षं मम
> च प्रियम् ॥

The Vedas, divided into three divisions, ultimately reveal the living entity as pure spirit soul. The Vedic seers and mantras, however, deal in esoteric terms, and I also am pleased by such confidential descriptions.

Now moving forward to Brahma Sūtra;

As Brahma Sūtra's very first Sutra ITSELF denotes Śrī Rām as it starts with, **“अथातो ब्रह्म जिज्ञासा"**

Here again “ अ ” is Referring to Awadh Dulare Sri Raghurāi. And although it's commentry already has been done by Vedās ITSELF, they have cleared that to whome this Brahma Sūtra refers;

> श्रीरामसान्निध्यवशाज्जगदानन्दकारिणी । उत्पत्तिस्थितिसंहारकारिणी
> सर्वदेहिनाम् सीता भगवती ज्ञेया मूलप्रकृतिसंज्ञिता प्रणवत्वात्प्रकृरिति
> वदन्ति ब्रह्मवादिन इति अथातो ब्रह्मजिज्ञासेति च ॥

Śrī Sītā has the constant company of Lord Śrī Rāma, because of which she is the benefactor of the world. They are the origin, condition and destruction of all living beings. Bhagwati Sita should be known as the original form of nature. because of their promiscuous nature Brahmoists call them ‘Prakriti'. In the Brahmā Sütrā, “Athatö Brahmā Jīggyasā”, her form has been depicted.

**(Atharvavedā Shākhāyam Sita Upanishad 1.7–8)**

That's our Janak Ladli Kishori Ju to whome this Brahma Sutra refers. Śrī Ladli Ju is Swayam Paratpār Par-Brahmā from whome every single power manifests;

> सा देवी त्रिविधा भवति शक्त्यासना इच्छाशक्तिः क्रियाशक्तिः
> साक्षाच्छक्तिरिति इच्छाशक्तिस्त्रिविधा भवति श्रीभूमिनीलात्मिका
> भद्ररूपिणी प्रभावरूपिणी सोमसूर्याग्निरूपा भवति

Śrī Sītā threefold manifests through Her power, namely the power of desire, the power of action, and the power of knowledge. Taking the incarnation of Śrī Devi, Bhudevi, Neeladevi, the one who benefits everyone with her influence, shines in the form of moon, sun and fire.

**(Atharvavedā Shākhāyam Sita Upanishad 1.11–12)**

Same is said by Brahmānd Purān,

> सीतायाश्च त्रिविधाशाः श्री भूनीलादिभेदतः । श्री भवेद् रुक्मिणी भूः
> स्यात् सत्यभामा वृढव्रता ॥ नीलास्याद् राधिका देवी सर्वलोकैक पूजिता ।

In short, Śrī Sītā manifests herself in three form Śrī, Bhu and Nila. By Śrī she becomes Rukmini by Bhu she becomes Satyabhama and by Nila she becomes Radha Rani Sarkār who is worshipped in all Lokas.

**(Quoted from Śrī Rām Paratva by Śrī Ramcharan Das Karunā Sindhu in 1750)**

That's why in Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmayan which is itself Incarnation of Vedās clearly says that Śrī Sītā is even Śrī of Bhagwāti Śrī.

> वसुधाया हि वसुधां श्रियः श्रीं भर्तृवत्सलाम् । सीतां
> सर्वानवद्याङ्गीमरण्ये विजने शुभाम् ।।

**(Valmiki Ramayan 6.111.24)**

> जेहि महुँ आदि मध्य अवसाना। प्रभु प्रतिपाद्य राम भगवाना।।

It's Śrī SītāRām who are being denoted in Beginning, Middle and at the end of Scriptures

> एतेचांशकलाभूताः शक्तिवीर्यबलान्विताः । रामचन्द्रांघ्रिसंजाता
> रामस्तुभगवान् स्वयम् ॥

(Maha-Ramayana, Canto-48, Shlok-37)

शक्ति, वीर्य, बल से युक्त ये उक्त अवतार सब अंश कलाभूत श्रीरामचन्द्र जी के चरण से उत्पन्न होते हैं और श्रीरघुनाथजी स्वयं पूर्ण भगवान हैं।

Śrī Rām and Śrimati Sītā Maharani are one as said in Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas;

> गिरा अरथ जल बीचि सम कहिअत भिन्न न भिन्न।

Who are separate in saying, like speech and its meaning and water and the wave of water, but are actually integral (one).

So anything that applies on Shri Ram will automatically apply on Awadh Dulari Shri Kishori Ju.

--End of the answer

Answer (score -1):

Every thing in this world has been created from the speech (Vāk)/ Prana (breath) of Ishwara in the form of Pranava and Vedas.

> *“Indeed, the Īśvara, in the beginning, created all things from the **words of the Vedas.** Truly, the names of the Rishis, and all else that has been created, occur in the Vedas”.  (MBH 12:232:26).*

> *“As clouds of smoke proceed by themselves out of a lighted fire kindled with damp fuel, thus, verily, O Maitreyî, has been breathed forth from this great Being what we have as Rig-veda, Yagur-veda, Sama-veda, Atharvâṅgirasas, Itihâsa (legends), Purâna (cosmogonies), Vidyâ (knowledge), the Upanishads, Slokas (verses), Sûtras (prose rules), Anuvyâkhyânas (glosses), Vyâkhyânas (commentaries). From him alone all these were breathed forth” (Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 2:4:10).*

The Brahman (Purusha) and Vāk are one and the same.:

> *“As far as the Braḥman extends, vāk extends till that place”. (Rig Veda 10:114:08).*

Rig Veda has a hymn called as ‘asya vAmIya sukta’ (Rig Veda 1:164); That sukta’s verse no. 45 talks about “catvāri vāk” (fourfold speech). It states that speech has fourfold division, three parts are hidden and only one part is what men speak of. The four divisions of speech are viz. – Parā, Paśyantī, Madhyamā and Vaikharī.

> *“Speech hath been measured out in four divisions; the Brahmans who have understanding know them. Three kept in close concealment cause no motion; of speech, men speak only the fourth division”. (Rig Veda 1:164:45).*

This fourfold division of speech is directly related to the fourfold division of Purusha of Rig Veda (10:90) where in verse no. 4 it states that from the fourth part of Purusha (Rudra) everything got created as stated below.:

> *“Three parts of his are beyond all this; all of this is but a part. Again and again, all that eats, and that eats not, appeared from this one part of His”. (Rig Veda 10:90:4).*

Aitareya Aranyaka says Prāṇa is the “Word” which is again identified as “Speech (vak)”. It uses the word “Prāṇa” and says that because Prāṇa entered into (pâdi) the creation, therefore he is called as ‘Pada’.:

> *“He (Prāṇa) is a Pada (word), for he got into all these beings. Because he got (pâdi) into all these beings, therefore there was the Pada (word). Therefore people call him who is really Prâna (breath), Pada”. (Aitareya Aranyaka 2:2:2:09).*

Aitareya Aranyaka further clarifies that Pada (Word) which is nothing but Prāṇa, is verily the syllables (aksharas) of the alphabet. For that reason it is verily Prāṇa who is called as ‘akśara’ (alphabets).:

> *“He (Prāṇa) is an Akshara (syllable), for he pours out (ksharati) gifts to all these beings, and without him no one can pour out (atiksharati) gifts. Therefore there was the Akshara (syllable). Therefore people call him who is really Prâna (breath), Akshara”. (Aitareya Aranyaka 2:2:2:10).*

Again,

> *“Thus all these Rik verses, all Vedas, all sounds are one word, viz. Prâna (breath). Let him know that Prâna is all Rik verses”.(Aitareya Aranyaka 2:2:2:11).*

In Brihadaranyaka Upanishad sages make enquiries to Yajnavalkya about the multiple gods and he answers them very aptly. Then finally the jury asks him who the one sole god is – who is called ‘Brahman’! – He answers it as – “Prāṇa” – as follows.:

> *“‘Which is the one god?’ ‘The Prāṇa (i.e., Ātmān) is the only God; it is Brahman, which is called Tyat (that)’(Brihadaranyaka Upanishad III:9:9).”.*

It's same as.:

> *“Rudra is truly one; for the knowers of Brahman do not admit the existence of a second, He alone rules all the worlds by His powers. He dwells as the inner Self of every living being. After having created all the worlds, He, their Protector, takes them back into Himself at the end of time” (Svetasvatara Upanishad 3:02).*

Also,

> *“Who are the Rudras?” "The ten Pranas and the Atman make eleven. These are the Rudras.” When the pranas and the atman leave the body, they make one cry in anguish. that's why they are called "Rudras” (Bri. Ar. Up. 3.9.4).*

The varṇamālā or aksharmāla are the form of Shiva and Shakti.:

> *“That moment the sustainer of the worlds viz. lord Vishnu started witnessing along with me (Brahma), a very beautiful and magnificent form (of lord Shiva). Hey Muni! He had five faces, ten hands, was as white in complexion as camphor, blazing with numerous types of auras, and decorated with various ornaments. He had an enormous belly, was blazing with splendour (veerya), and had all the characteristics of being a Supreme Purusha. Seeing such a form I and Hari became filled with gratitude”. (śiva purāṇa 2:08:28-30).*

> *“Then that Maheshwara, who is also called Parameshwara being pleased displayed his illustrious form comprising of ṣabda (akṣara). His head was ‘akāra’, his forehead was the elongated ‘a’ syllable i.e., ‘ākāra’, his right eye was ‘e’, i.e., ‘ikāra’, and his left eye was the elongated ‘e’, syllable i.e., ‘īkāra’, the syllable ‘u (ukāra)’ was his right ear, and the elongated one ‘ū (ūkāra)’ was his left ear. The ‘r̥kāra’ was the right cheek of that paramēṣṭhī and ‘r̥ūkāra’ was his left cheek. The syllables ‘lr̥’ and ‘lr̥u’ were his two nostrils and ‘ēkāra’ and ‘aikāra’ were respectively the upper and lower lips. The syllables ‘ō’ and ‘au’ were seen as the upper and lower teeth respectively. The palate of that wielder of trident was seen as ‘aṁ’. The group of five syllables viz. ‘ka, kha, ga, gha, ṇga’ were his five right hands and the group of syllables starting with ‘cha’ (viz., ‘cha, chha, ja, jha, jna’ were his five left hands. The group of five syllables beginning with ‘ṭa’ (‘ṭa, Ṭa, da, ḍha, ṇa’) and the group beginning with ‘ta’ (‘ta, tha, da, dha, na’), were respectively his right and left fēt respectively. The syllable ‘pa’, was his belly and ‘pha’ is said to be his back. ‘ba’ is said to be his left back side and ‘bha’ is said to be his skanda. The heart of that Yogi, the great God is ‘ma’ syllable and the seven syllables ranging from ‘ya’ to ‘sa’ are the seven elements of that lord called as vibhu. His navel is the ‘ha-kāra’ and ‘kṣa’ syllable is his fragrance”. (śiva purāṇa 2:08:31-39).*

A beautiful Prayer to Bhagawan Shiva by Lord Vishnu in Suta Samhita of Sri Skanda Purana.:

> *“Salutations to you whose body (form) is composed of matrkas (akara to kshkara alphabets). You are the witnesser of the triad (triputi) named ‘pramaata-pramana-prameya’. Through the matrka-mantras it is you who are obtained. You are great (58). You are alone the adhara (foundation) of even matrikas. Even the original form of matrikas (i.e., a-kara) is also you. It is you only who are denoted by pranava (omkara) etc., mahamantras. Salutations to you, who are the great Brahman (59). Existing in the two fold division of vowels and consonants, the mahamantras denote you alone. It is you alone who take up all the positions, but (in reality) you are devoid of them. Salutations to you who are such a great efficient lord (60)”. (sūta saṁhita 4:29:58-60).*

> *“Although you are nishkala you have made yourself appear in the eightfold form of eight sets of alphabets; you’ve assumed the form of all words and innumerable meanings (61). Although you are obtained through the help of words (śabda), yet you have no relation with śabdas (words) [means you are beyond the reach of words]. You are alone the one who shines with your own self effulgence, salutations to you who are such (62)” (sūta saṁhita 4:29:61-62).*

Same is the form of Mata Lalita aka Matrika Parmeshwari.:

> *(Lalita Trishati Introduction: 25).:
> “O pot-born sage, for each of the 15 akśara-s beginning with ka, there are 20 names describing them in this 300 names (trishati) which will bring fulfillment and completion to everything”.*

> *(Lalita Trishati 01a).:
> “Devi! You are represented by the alphabet ‘Ka’ (since you are identical with Shiva who is the creator of the universe in the form of ‘Ka’). You’re Kalyani (Being auspicious and bestower of the highest happiness of brahmananda)”.*

> *(Lalita Trishati 02a).:
> “Devi! You are represented by the alphabet ‘ē’ (which stands for Shakti identical to Brahman). You’re mono-syllable (a-kāra which is the seed for all the ‘akśaras’ and represents the state of Brahman)”.*

> *(lalitā sahasranāma stōtra: verse 116).:
> “(Lalita) whose form is of the form of varṇamāla i.e., alphabets from akara to kshakara”.*

> *(lalitā sahasranāma stōtra: verse 34).:
> “She, whose lotus like face represents the divine Vagbhava group (5 syllable s)”.*

> *(lalitā sahasranāma stōtra: verse 35a).:
> “From throat to the waist, she represents madhyakūṭa (6 syllables)”.*

> *(lalitā sahasranāma stōtra: verse 35b).:
> “From waist downwards till feet she represents śaktikūta (4 syllables)”.*

Again,

> *sūta saṁhitā 4:4:18.:
> “The Mātr̥kā Paramēśvarī is the mother of all mantrās”.*

> *sūta saṁhitā 4:4:21.:
> “As the Supreme Shiva appears in twofold form as Shiva and Shakti, in the same manner Matrika Devi also exists in twofold state”.*

> *sūta saṁhitā 4:4:22.:
> “Through one form she denotes Shakti and through another one she denotes Shiva. Therefore, she who manifests through word (pada), the path to attain the paramapada is verily this vidya alone”.*

> *sūta saṁhitā 4:4:23.:
> “That shiva who is beyond the reach of speech, hence is called apadam (no-speech i.e., turIya), with the help of his own Shakti assumes the state of pada (word i.e., speech) and pada (word or speech) again leads us to that state of apada (Shiva beyond speech). One who understands this division of apada and pada he verily sees (i.e., he becomes brahman)”.*

As for A-Kara.:

> *“He who knows this speech of which this (the mahaduktha) is a development, he is clever. ‘A (akāra)’ is the whole of speech, and manifested through different kinds of contact (consonants) and of wind (sibilants), it becomes manifold and different”. (Aitareya Aranyaka 2:3:6:14).*

> *sūta saṁhitā 4:4:27.:
> “The one single Matrika for the benefit of the worlds became many”.*

NANDIKĒŚVARA KĀSIKĀ on Maheshvara Sutras and A-Kara.:

Nandikēśwara had written a wonderful commentary on the “Maheshwara Sutras” to explain the hidden secrets of creation of universe from those aphorisms. His commentary is known as **‘nandikēśvara kāsikā’**, and the legendary sage Upamanyu wrote a magnificent commentary over the commentary (i.e., vārtika) of Nadikeshwara to elaborate what nandi had explained. Who other than the illustrious sage Upamanyu (the guru of Sri Krishna) could grasp the finer secrets outlined by Nandikēśwara of the aphorisms of Śiva? Upamanyu’s commentary goes by the name of **‘tatwa vimarśinī’**.

> *nandikēśwara kāśika Intro 01: tatvavimarśinī intro 01:e.:
> “Revealing the Supreme nature of the Atman **that is himself**, which is beyond the reach of speech etc., senses, with the desire to uplift Sanaka and others; by the means of sounding the hand-drum, he sounded it nine and five times i.e., fourteen times (at the end of his dance) to manifest **the Supreme reality that is inherent in Him”**.*

> *nandikēśwara kāśika intro 01:tatvavimarśinī intro 01:f-g.:
> “The first collection of Lord Shiva’s aphorisms, **related to Shiva himself**, which are deepest secrets which are auspicious, which are in the form of letters of the sound that emanated (form the hand-drum), I’ll explain clearly by pondering over them. The word ‘vimarsha’ has been used for the sake of metrical requirements”.*

> *(nandikēśvara kāśikā 03).:
> “The letter ‘a’ is the form of Brahman devoid of attributes dwelling in all objects, combined with the letter ‘i’ which is the consciousness, the letter ‘u’ is the ‘īśvara’ (lord) of the universe”.*

> *(nandikēśvara kāśikā 04).:
> “The syllable ‘a’, the first among all alphabets, is the effulgent supreme lord. From the combination of the first and last letters the word ‘aham’ is born”.*

> *(tatvavimarśinī 03).:
> “The first letter ‘a’ is united with the last letter ‘ha’. All the letters from ‘a’ to ‘ha’ are born from the Supreme Shiva”.*

> *(nandikēśvara kāśikā 05-06).:
> “In the beginning the entire universe was only in the form of parā consciousness. From that parā was born paśyantī and the vāk which originated from that was known as madhyamā (5). This vāk is known as vaikharī when it emerges from the face through the viśuddhi-chakra. By its origin and manifestation it is similar to madhyamā (6)”.*

> *(tatvavimarśinī 05-06:a).:
> “…and later (the vāk) as vaikharī in the mouth and thus assumes the form of the vēdās”.*

The Universe is created from speech.:

> *(tatvavimarśinī 05-06:b).:
> “Śruti (Vēdās) also says, “It is only the speech which created the worlds”. It means that it is only the subtle aspect of speech which transforms itself in the form of this world”.*

Only 1/4th of Speech is use for talking as told earlier also.:

> *(tatvavimarśinī 05-06:c)
> ”In another śruti passage it has been said: ‘The world with its multiple forms is composed of speech only, and having divided, one part of it is being experienced”.*

Speech creates everything in the form of vedas.:

> *(MBH 12:232:24).:
> “At the outset the Self-born caused those excellent Vedic sounds, that are embodiments of knowledge and that have neither beginning nor end to (spring up and) flow on (from preceptor to disciple). From those sounds have sprung all kinds of actions”.*

> *(MBH 12:232:25).:
> “The names of the Rishis, all things that have been created, the varieties of form seen in existent things, and the course of actions, have their origin in the Vedas”.*

> *(MBH 12:232:27).:
> “Upon the expiration of his night (i.e., at the dawn of his day), the uncreate Brahman creates, from prototypes that existed before, all things which are, of course, well-made by Him. In the Vedas hath been indicated the topic of the Soul’s Emancipation, along with the ten means constituted by study of the Vedas, adoption of the domestic mode of life, penances, observance of duties common to all the modes of life, sacrifices, performance of all such acts as lead to pure fame, meditation which is of three kinds, and that kind of emancipation which is called success (Siddhi) attainable in this life”.*

Akshara are retah (seed), kama (desire), Purusha (man), Prakriti (woman).

A-Kara is Purusha like Maheshwar-a.
I-Kara is Prakriti like Maheshwar-i.

Combination of the two is the Universe.

> *(nandikēśvara kāśikā 07-08).:
> “Due to the nearness of the syllable ‘i’ (ikāra) with that of the syllable ‘a’ (akāra), the syllable ‘i’ is the cause of the universe and due to its prospective nature, it is the cause of all the alphabets in the varṇamāla (7). When there arose desire to create the universe, then the world became (i.e., came into existence). The seers who were learned in Vedas called it ‘kāmabīja’ (the seed of desire) (8)”.*

> *(Rig Veda 9:74:5).:
> “ The Soma-stalk hath roared, following with the wave: he swells with sap for man the skin which Gods enjoy. Upon the lap (womb) of Aditi he lays the germ, by means whereof we gain children and progeny”.*

> *(Rig Veda 10:129:04).:
> “Thereafter rose Desire (kāma) in the beginning, Desire (kāma), the primal seed (retaḥ) and germ of Spirit. Sages who searched with their heart’s thought discovered the existent’s kinship in the non-existent”.*

> *BG 10:33.: Among all syllable, I am A-Kara.*

**Conclusion.:** Speech is Brahman itself. Where a single syllable A-Kara is the retah (seed) which multiplies itself into various Aksharas and thus the Universe is form with the help of I-Kara.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..